# Large rectangle with perimeter 300 cm divided into smaller identical rectangles.

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

A large rectangle whose perimeter is 300 cm, is divided into a number of identical rectangles, each of perimeter 58 cm. Each side of these rectangles is a whole number of cm. Show that there are exactly two possibilities for the number of smaller rectangles.
[image]

My solution so far:

Larger rectangle $2x+2y=300\Rightarrow x+y=150$

Smaller rectangles $2x+\frac{2y}{n}=58\Rightarrow x+\frac{y}{n}=29\Rightarrow x=29-\frac{y}{n}$ for some $n\in Z$.

This gives

$29-\dfrac{y}{n}+y=150$

$y-\dfrac{y}{n}=121$

$y\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=121$

Now this means that the pairs of product can only be 1 and 121, 11 and 11, and 121 and 1. However, this can't be. Where did I go wrong? Or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: You should define your variables and not reuse them.  If the large rectangle is $x \times y$, you should not use $x$ for a side of the small rectangle unless you show they are the same.  Why should the small rectangles be the same width as the large one?  Maybe you cut the large one in both dimensions.

Comment: Even worse, you cannot assume the small rectangles are all oriented in the same direction.  Think of cutting a $5 \times 6$ rectangle into $2 \times 3$ rectangles.  You can do it with a stack of three horizontal making $3 \times 6$ plus two vertical making $2 \times 6$

Answer (score 0):

Let the small rectangles be $z \times (29-z)$ with $z \lt 15$ and there be $n$ of them.  The area of the large rectangle is then $nz(29-z)$.  If one dimension of the large rectangle is $w$ we get 
$$nz(29-z)=w(150-w)\\
29nz-nz^2=150w-w^2\\
w^2-150w+29nz-nz^2=0\\
w=75\pm\sqrt{nz^2-29nz+5625}$$
I made a spreadsheet to search for solutions and I find
$$\begin {array} {r r r r r} n&z&\text{small}&\text{large}&\text{OK}\\
\hline 12&6&6\times 23&12\times 138&\text{yes}\\
14&4&4\times 25&10\times 140\\
16&2&2\times 27&6\times 144\\
18&8&8\times 21&24\times 126&\text{yes}\\
12&11&11\times 18&18 \times 132&\text{yes}\\
23&13&13 \times 16&46 \times 104\\
24&12&12\times 17&48 \times 102&\text{yes}\\
26&4&4\times 25&20\times 130\\
28&8&8\times 21&42\times 108\\
27&13&13 \times 16&72\times78
\end {array}$$
Where yes in the OK column means the small rectangles can tile the large one in an obvious way.  I claim the problem is wrong and there are three possibilities for the number of smaller rectangles
$$12,18,24$$

Comment: I find $16$ valid dissections with $13$ distinct counts for the smaller rectangles.